# Регулярное выражение превод строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, подскажите пожалуйста, модифицировать данное регулярное выражение: при нажатии клавиши `Enter` идёт переход на новую строку, и в вызалит ошибка ссылающаяся на пробелы, даже если увеличить количество разрешённых пробелов, при переходе на новую строку все равно появляется это сообщение об ошибке.
использую вот это: [ссылка](https://github.com/jquense/yup).

---

Возможно можно дописать в регулярное выражение, количество переходов на новую строку, но я перевернул весь интеренет и не нашёл ответа на этот вопрос.
Вероятно я как новичёк, не совсем понимаю как работать с регулярными выражения, надеюсь на вашу помощь!

```js
export const getAboutStockValidation = () =>
  Yup.string()
  .trim()
  .matches(/^((?!\s{2}).)*$/, 'Не более одного пробела между словами')
  .min('10', 'Минимум 10 символов')
  .max('250', 'Максимум 250 символов');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `/^(?![^]*\s{2})/`? Или `/^(?![^]*[^\S\r\n]{2})/`? Кстати, это "регулярные выражения", а не "регулярные уравнения".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Исправил, большое спасибо!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew пренесите пожалуйста ваш комментарий в ответы, что бы я смог выбрать его в качестве правильного ответа, и вам зачислили очки репутации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Главная проблема — `.` не находит знаков перехода на новую строку. Кроме того, используемая конструкция слишком громоздка, достаточно ограничиться одним блоком просмотра вперёд:

```
/^(?![^]*\s{2})/
```

`^(?![^]*\s{2})` находит начало строки (`^`), а потом, если находит 0 и более любых символов, за которыми следует 2 любых пробельных символа, возваращает `false`.

Если необходимо отсеять совпадания с 2+ "вертикальными" пробельными символами, используйте

```
/^(?![^]*[^\S\r\n]{2})/
```

`[^\S\r\n]` находит только "горизонтальные" пробельные символы (за исключением некоторых нетипичных переходов на новую строку, но этого шаблона чаще всего достаточно).